# Is declaring non pointer variables in a function a memory leak?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

As the title suggests, does declaring non-pointer variables in a function a memory leak? I looked all over for it on the Internet and I did find one answer, but it was for C and I wasn't sure if the same rules applied to C++. I am currently improving an older project of mine and I am trying to be more memory efficient. As an example, I have a loading function that will be called at least 10-20 times just during start up and I was wondering what effect would declaring non-pointer variables have on memory.

```
void ObjectLoaderManager::loadObject(char FileName[20])
{

    char file[100] = "Resources\Models\"; // Declare object file path
    strncat_s (File, FileName, 20);           // Combine the file path with the input name
    std::string newName;                      // Declare a new scring
    newFile = File;                           // Assign File to the string newFile


    int health = 10;
    // Assign newFile as the name of the newly created object and assign health variable
    // in later parts of the function
}
```

While I do understand parts of this function are blatantly bad and a lot of these are not practices I would not do, however, I am curious to know what effect declaring non-pointer variables over and over would do in a localized function. Thank you.
Here is the link to the article I mentioned at the start of the post http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html

Comment: You might want that object file path to be escaped properly.

Comment: Oh it is written differently in what I am doing now. I just used it as an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, any local vars declared in a function are allocated on the stack, so unless the function is called multiple times recursively it is a non-issue.

Comment: That said, many beginners to programming will declare a rather large array on the stack and immediately blow it out, or worse come close and overflow later, which is always fun.

Comment: I personally think that beginners should not overthink concepts like memory management and such but rather focus on the important stuff being the problem that they are solving. Anybody can figure out where his memory went when they gets some experience...